# lazy re-implementation of Clojure Interleaving

Tags: clojure, lazy-loading

I want to rewrite (I'm not sure if the original implementation is lazy of not) a lazy implementation of clojure interleaving using `lazy-seq` that works like this :

```
(take 4 (lazy-interleave ’( 1 2 3) ’( a b c)))
(1 a 2 b)
```

I came up with something like this, but I'm not sure why it doesn't work:

```
 (defn lazy-interleave [v1 v2]
   (lazy-seq (concat (list (first v1) (first v2))) (lazy-interleave (next v1) (next v2)))
   )
```

**Edit:**

Thanks to Arthur's answer, here is a modified working solution:

```
(defn lazy-interleave [v1 v2]
    (lazy-seq
      (cons (first v1) (cons (first v2) (lazy-interleave (rest v1) (rest v2))))
      )
   )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of reformatting reveals the problem:

```
(defn lazy-interleave [v1 v2]
  (lazy-seq
   (concat (list (first v1) (first v2)))
   (lazy-interleave (next v1) (next v2))))
```

In other words, you're constructing a lazy sequence that, when realized, will evaluate `(concat (list (first v1) (first v2)))`, ignore the result, and then try to evaluate and return `(lazy-interleave (next v1) (next v2))`. This call to `lazy-interleave` does the same thing, again dropping the first elements of `v1` and `v2`, and so on, ad infinitum.

You never get to the bottom because you have no empty check, and so since `(next nil)` returns `nil`, it just keeps going even after you exhaust both sequences. You don't get a `StackOverflowError` because you're using lazy sequences instead of recursion.

A correct implementation would look like this:

```
(defn lazy-interleave [v1 v2]
  (when (and (seq v1) (seq v2))
    (lazy-cat [(first v1) (first v2)]
              (lazy-interleave (rest v1) (rest v2)))))
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there is a `lazy-cat`. Just one question: even without `nil` checking with lazy-cat we can `take` a limited number of elements from `lazy-interleave`, but why we can't do it with lazy-seq? in your example I'll get `(1 nil)` for `(take 2 (lazy-interleave [1] []))`, but even using `take` my code doesn't work

Comment: As a programmer that likes cats, I try to use that function whenever it can be made to fit

Comment: though in just about all cases you can just call `concat` which is also lazy.

Answer (score 1):

`interleave` is already lazy:

```
user> (interleave (take 5 (iterate #(do (println "sequence A:" %) (inc %)) 0))
                  (take 5 (iterate #(do (println "sequence B:" %) (inc %)) 100)))
sequence A: 0
sequence B: 100
sequence A: 1
sequence B: 101
sequence A: 2
sequence B: 102
sequence A: 3
sequence B: 103
(0 100 1 101 2 102 3 103 4 104)


user> (take 4 (interleave (take 5 (iterate #(do (println "sequence A:" %) (inc %)) 0))
                          (take 5 (iterate #(do (println "sequence B:" %) (inc %)) 100))))
sequence A: 0
sequence B: 100
(0 100 1 101)
```

And the core of it's implementation looks much like your example:

```
(lazy-seq
      (let [s1 (seq c1) s2 (seq c2)]
        (when (and s1 s2)
          (cons (first s1) (cons (first s2) 
                                 (interleave (rest s1) (rest s2)))))))
```

Except it also works on more than two sequences, so it has another arity that handles that case.